# Why are there no alternate CDs?

Tags: installation, kubuntu, cd, alternate

In trying to download the latest release, I see there are no alternate CDs available.  Previously I have needed them in order to install with a linux software raid root.  Does the lack of alternate CDs mean that all of those features are within the others? or have they not been finished yet?

I ideally wanted a kubuntu alternate CD but I see there is not an ubuntu one either.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prior to Ubuntu 12.10 ,you are able to upgrade your Ubuntu OS with the help of Ubuntu Alternate CD. But with the release of Ubuntu 12.10, Steve Langasek from Canonical announced on August 27th, 2012, a proposal to drop the Alternate CD ISO images starting with the upcoming Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) operating system.

On August 30th, the Alternate CDs were gone from the daily builds and will not be available at the launch of Ubuntu 12.10 Beta 1. For more information your can go through following link.

- [Proposal to drop Ubuntu alternate CDs for 12.10](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-August/035675.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll install from an older one.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no alternate CDs neither for [Ubuntu](http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/) nor for [Kubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.10/release/). But there is one for [Lubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.10/release/)!